# Can someone help me understand these Spanish sentences?

Tags: traducción

> Cuando ando con mi esposa no se me para. Pero cuando le ando poniendo
> los cuernos se me para normal.

Yo realmente no entiendo nada de estas oraciones. Supongo que el sentido es algo no literal.

Comment: Podría decirse que sí. Estas oraciones son de sujeto tácito, es decir está implícito. Si dice que ‘se le para’, hay algo que se tiene que parar ¿Qué cosas se le podrán parar a este señor?

Comment: [Acá va otra ayuda más](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/poner_los_cuernos). Ahora, explicame vos el significado de la frase.

Comment: La palabras son españolas, pero la frase no. Lo que se para (el corazón, ... o lo que sea) puede quedar tácito,  pero las comas hay que ponerlas. En este caso, que falten comas no cambia el sentido de la frase (como  en  "Vamos a comer, niños." vs. "Vamos a comer niños") , es que dejan a las frases sin sentido alguno,  hasta que te imaginas donde debían ir las comas, y ya lo traduces mentalmente al español.

Comment: En España (excepto en Murcia) "parar" se relaciona con "detener", "cesar el movimiento". Por eso nos cuesta entender la frase. Pero la 7ª acepción del DLE es "poner algo o a alguien de pie o en posición vertical". Eso, junto con el resto de la frase, da una idea de lo que se trata.

Answer (score 2):

"Se me para" in this case should be understood as "I have an erection". "Poniendo los cuernos" as "cheating on". "Ando" as "I'm". Therefore the meaning of the sentence would be: *When I'm with my wife I don't have an  erection, but when I'm cheating on her I have an erection normally*

Comment: Cannot understand the downvote here, Toto's anwser is accurate.